# Update all columns with the value of NULL

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I have a very simple table let's call it Samsung.  In this table I have a column called description with two values with samsung_id of 200 & 201.  For these two entries, I have a value for description of "NULL."  I want to be able to update all of these. I know I can run the following comand:

```
UPDATE SAMSUNG
SET description = 'square'
WHERE samsung_id = 200 OR samsung_id = 201;
```

To achieve my desired results, but what if your table had 1,000 entries and you didn't want to list them out.  How would you run this command to take out all the values of NULL and replace with square.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE SAMSUNG
SET description = 'square'
WHERE description IS NULL
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I am learning SQL and I was thinking it would be something like `WHERE description = NULL`  Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE SAMSUNG
SET description = 'square'
WHERE description IS NULL or description = 'NULL'
```

In case you save a string value 'NULL' in your description.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this command along with rbedger's both work.  Yours will allow me to ensure I keep all the description values no matter what.

Comment: Actually, it won't allow you to keep values.  It simply allows you to update records.  It does not prevent subsequent updates.  If you want to do that, add a not null constraint to the column.